# converting Salesforce Leads via active assignment rule is going wrong

Tags: assignment-rules

going through Admin 201 session in development environment

created a Lead >> selected region (custom field)

Used active assignment rule checkbox and it is automatically changing the name of the lead to one particular user.

Tried (deactivating) freezing the user but still no luck. Not sure what assignments I have made that it always changes the name to one particular user.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of what it looks like after the assignment.

Comment: here is the link to all images 1) when the lead is created I selected the region and used active assignment button at the very bottom. as soon I hit save you can see that in comment section it says you have changed the lead name.   http://tinypic.com/r/30rxhc6/9

Answer (score 1):

Go to Setup>Build>Customise>Leads>Lead Assignment Rules and check if an assignment rules are in place and are active.

[image: Lead Assignment rules]

Then you can change the user for the assignment or deactivate the assignment rules. If the rule is deactivated then if the Lead owner is a User they will retain ownership otherwise if the Lead is owned by a Queue then ownership normally be assigned to the User doing the lead conversion.

Comment: Thank you for this answer but the issue is a bit different, I am creating a lead, by using active assignment rule, it should go to "US Sales Team". It is going to the US Sales team but it is also changing the name of the lead. deactivating the assignment rules definitely works but not sure why it is changing the Name of the Lead being converted to a particular user in the system.

Comment: Ok, I'll see if I can duplicate that in a Dev org as I've not seen it happen before. Have a look to see if there is any Apex code for lead conversion in the org as Lead field mapping does not include the account name.

Comment: I have got the solution, I was going crazy over it, when I was learning triggers I created a simple hello word trigger which was updating leads on update and setting first name and last name to a specifically defined name. deactivating the trigger resolved the issue.